# Why doesn't border-collapse work in html2pdf?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I want to create a pdf with an html table like : [image: tableEx]

So, I created this html :

```
<table style="width: 100%; border:2px solid; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
        <th style="border-left: 1px solid; width: 60%;">Ref produit</th>
        <th style="border-left: 1px solid; width: 10%;">Taille</th>
        <th style="border-left: 1px solid; width: 10%;">Quantit�</th>
        <th style="border-left: 1px solid; width: 10%;">Prix net HT</th>
        <th style="border-left: 1px solid; width: 10%;">Montant HT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid;">BAL100</td>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid; text-align: center;">S</td>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid; text-align: center;">20</td>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid; text-align: center;">22.00</td>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid; text-align: center;">440</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    .
    .
    .
    </tr>
</table>
```

The pdf result is:

[image]

The borders disappeared!

If I remove the property `border-collapse: collapse;` the borders appear but the result is not appropriate.

<del>I see on the [official forum](http://www.yaronet.com/en/posts.php?s=119507) (french post) that</del> the property border-collapse works only on the tag `table`. So I don't understand why my table is not generated properly.

Any idea?

Here is my php code to generate the pdf

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent);
$html2pdf->Output($path, 'F');
```

Comment: Have you tried to set border color? i.e. `1px solid black`

Comment: how are you creating the pdf from the html?

Comment: @AryehArmon On the bottom of my question there are 3 php lines, `$htmlContent` contain my html. I use the library html2pdf

Comment: what version of html2pdf are you using?

Comment: @enigma html2pdf => 4.03 and tcpdf => 4.0.014

Comment: i think it's due to your table width, try decreasing your table width by 90% or some thing. and give <table border="1">

Comment: @TouqeerShafi Same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`border-collapse: collapse;` is supposed to merge two of the same, adjacent borders together. When using it in html2pdf, you should style both the `border-left` and `border-right` attributes (as the same thing), which when collapsed will produce a single border. Also, to write this CSS defensively, and not assume the `border-color` attribute inheritance, you should technically specify it when defining border, such as `border: 1px solid black;`

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround, if I replace the css property `border-collapse: collapse;` by `cellspacing="0"` the result looks OK.

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border:2px solid;position: relative;">
```

Comment: But I don't understand why `border-collapse` doesn't work, because it's in the css [compatibility list](http://www.studentenwerk-goettingen.de/pdf/help/compatibility.css.2.1.html).

Comment: web.archive link for compat list: https://web.archive.org/web/http://www.studentenwerk-goettingen.de/pdf/help/compatibility.css.2.1.html

Comment: How it should works without `color`? Unfortunately, your solution not works for me. My solution is to create div wrapper over text with `border: 1px solid black` and add border to td: `padding: 5px`

Comment: @IvanTikhonov The default color of `border` is black

Answer (score 0):

As @andrewgu suggested, I set border for every th/td, but only top, right and left borders to make border thinner. As result I had the following css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;

    tr {
        &:last-child {
            td,
            th {
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
        }

        th {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;

            &:last-child {
                border-right: 1px solid black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem was some shaded cells cover top border which was set for tr. CSS above solved this and all borders are visible.